# What gam family to use to get cumulative probability?

Tags: regression, probability, generalized-additive-model

I'm trying to model probability of specific deviation under defined conditions.
For condition [C1,C2,C3] i have a value describing the deviation D. Obviously, if deviation D was achieved then all probabilities for achieving deviation D1 P(C1,C2,C3,Dx) describing probability P of achieving deviation of at least Dx under conditions C1,C2,C3? I'm working in R but any pseudocode will do.

Edit:
Let me show you what I need by example:

I have a time series. For simplicity we can assume it's price reading.
I also have some filters applied on my series. For simplicity let them be running means of three different lengths (windows). For each reading I'll take some number of presequent readings and calculate standard mean. Let's say the means are of length 5, 15, 60. I will then calculate differentials of these readings (sometimes called slopes too, or tangents) and they will be my C1, C2, C3.

For simplicity let's also assume that my Deviations (D) are just usual price differences from current price (current reading). By current I mean the price that is at the moment when conditions C1, C2, C3 are read.

I'm going to have a statistics of how far  did the price move (maximum distance it had) in 60 periods following the reading, paired with associated data of C1, C2, C3.

This means, that if price deviated by 11 points, it also deviated by 10, and 9,8,... before it reached 11. Like in scoring: If you get A, you are better then the people that scored B. If someone asks what is a probability that person will pass assuming conditions (like the person learned for 8h total, where it was also 2h in last week) you need to cumulate A,B,C and D scores in you model. Yet here, the number of scoress is uncountable.

So, I want to build a statistic of what is a probability of reaching some deviation in situation where conditions ar C1, C2, C3.

I understand that simple logit regression will not fit scenario where some ordering is assumed.[image: I used trading view to illustrate this example]

Is it even possible or do I have to create a logit regression and query the model for all possible deviations and then cumulate the probabilities like in ecdf?

Comment: Can you please provide some additional information on what you want to achieve? I somehow think that ordinal regression might be associated with what you want but I cannot understand enough from your current problem description.

Comment: @usεr11852 I've updated the description. Thanks :)